# Preciso jogar uma variável php no javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um código onde preciso colocar dentro de um javascript uma variável que é a ID da pessoa que estou puxando, mas não consigo encontrar a solução. Onde estou errando?

```
<?php echo "
                <tr>
                <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
                <td>".$row['telefone']."</td>
                <td>".$idade."</td>
                <td>".$row['cidade']."</td>
                <td>".$row['cargo_pretendido']."</td>

                <td><button onclick='mostrar()' class='w3-button w3-black'>INFOk123</button><td>
                </tr>

                <div id='id\"$row['id']\"' class='w3-modal'>
                    <div class='w3-modal-content'>
                        <header class='w3-container w3-teal'>
                            <span onclick='sumir()' class='w3-button w3-display-topright'>&times;</span>
                        </header>
                        <p>Teste</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

          ";
    }
    echo "<br>";

}


?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    function mostrar() { 
       document.getElementById('id"<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"').style.display='block'; 
    }

    function sumir() { 
       document.getElementById('id"<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"').style.display='none'; 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Aqui: `document.getElementById('id<?php echo $row['id']; ?>').style.display='block';` e aqui: `<div id='id".$row['id']."' class='w3-modal'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está recebendo o ID de forma dinamica, o ideal seria receber o ID nas funções:

```
//Receber o ID nas funções
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function mostrar(id) { 
   document.getElementById(id).style.display='block'; 
}

function sumir(id) { 
   document.getElementById(id).style.display='none'; 
}

</script>
```

E passar o ID como parametro quando for gerar o html com php

```
<td><button onclick=\"mostrar('id".$row['id']."')\" class='w3-button w3-black'>INFOk123</button><td>
            </tr>

            <div id='id".$row['id']."' class='w3-modal'>
                <div class='w3-modal-content'>
                    <header class='w3-container w3-teal'>
                        <span onclick=\"sumir('id".$row['id']."')\" class='w3-button w3-display-topright'>&times;</span>
                    </header>
                    <p>Teste</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Essa resposta deu certo, agora entendi como funciona! Obrigado!